# About closure under +

Tags: linear-algebra

> $Q$: Find a subset of $ \mathbb R^3$ which is closed under $*$, but not $+$.
>
> $A$: The set $\mathbb R$$u$ $+$ $\mathbb R$$v$, where $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent vectors in $ \mathbb R^3$. Here $ \mathbb R$$w$ = $\{aw: a \in \mathbb R\}$ for a given vector $w$. This is closed under $*$, but not $+$.

By

> $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent vectors in $ \mathbb R^3$

do they mean two sets of linearly independent vectors $u$ and $v$ in $ \mathbb R^3$ where $u$ could be  $u = \{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)\}$?

Generally, please help me understand how this set is not closed under $+$. Thanks.

Comment: What does $\ast$ represent here? Anyway, by “$u$ and $v$ are linearly independent vectors” they mean exactly that: $u$ and $v$ are two single, independent vectors, but other than that property, the choice of $u$ and $v$ is unimportant; any two vectors will work as long as they are linearly independent.

Comment: Scalar multiplication.

Comment: But it does not make sense to ask for a set closed under scalar multiplication.  A subset $S$ is “closed” under an operator $\star$ if $a\star b$ is in $S$ whenever $a$ and $b$ are. But if $\ast$ is scalar multiplication, $a\ast b$ is not even a vector, so it is never in any set $S$ of vectors that might contain $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Are you sure it says $\Bbb R u + \Bbb R v$, not $\Bbb R u \cup \Bbb R v$?

Comment: I think it should be the set $ S = \mathbb R u \cup \mathbb R v $, which is "closed under scalar multiplication" in that $ x \in S \implies \lambda x \in S $ but $ u + v $ can't be in $ S $ for the hypothesis of linear independence.

Comment: Here is the link to the question(second Q): (http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/115a.3.02f/assign1.pdf) and here's the link to the answer: (http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/115a.3.02f/solutions1.pdf)

Comment: @MJD I've seen UG textbooks use "closed under scalar multiplication" for a subset $S$ of a vector space over $K$ to mean  $av\in S$ for all $v\in S$ and $a\in K$, although I agree this doesn't exactly fit with the usual meaning of "closed". That seems to be the idea here. I agree that the $+$ sign should be a $\cup$ to make the answer correct.

Comment: Extra aside for the OP: if $u\in\mathbb{R}^3$, then $u$ cannot be *equal* to the set $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$, but it could be a member of this set. There are also lots of pairs of linearly independent vectors that are not subsets of this three element set, like $(1,-1,0)$ and $(0,1,-1)$.

Comment: Can a single vector be linearly independent? I was told only a set of vectors can be linearly independent.

Comment: @Afghanistan: That's true: "linear independence" is a property of sets of vectors. The author writes "$u$ and $v$ are linearly independent" as a more readable form of the technically-correct "$\{u,v\}$ is linearly independent".

Answer (score 1):

More concretely, you can take $u = (1,0,0)$ and $v = (0,1,0)$, which are linearly independent.
Then you have the set of point of the form **either** $(x,0,0)$ **or** $(0,y,0)$, for some constant $x$ **or** $y$.  Then you can check this is closed under scalar multiplication, but not under addition since for example
$$
(1,0,0) + (0,1,0) = (1,1,0)
$$
is not in the set.

Equivalently, the set $S$ above is the set of points $(x,y,z)$ where $xy = 0$ and $z = 0$.

Comment: But the set is $\mathbb{R}v+\mathbb{R}u$, if $u=(1,0,0),v=(0,1,0)$, then $\mathbb{R}v+\mathbb{R}u=\{(\alpha,\beta,0),\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}\}$, any sum of elements in this space is still in the space.

Comment: @ellya I see the confusion.  They have made a mistake.  They mean the union of $\mathbb{R}v$ and $\mathbb{R}u$ and not the sum.

Comment: ohh... yeah then all is fine :)